# Error while trying to accept generic types that extend a class in an interface

Tags: java, oop

In this code:

```java
public interface LinkedList<T> {
   <N extends Node<T>> Optional<N> findNodeByData(T data);
   // ...
}
```

```java
public class SinglyLinkedListNode<T> extends Node<T> {
   // ...
}
```

```java
public class Node<T> {
   // ...
}
```

```java
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> implements LinkedList<T> {
   public Optional<SinglyLinkedListNode<T>> findNodeByData(T data){
      // ...
   }
}
```

My goal is to have the method in interface accept any class that extends `Node<T>`, as `N`.

I get the error `'findNodeByData(T)' in 'com.starosti.datastructures.linkedlist.singly.SinglyLinkedList' clashes with 'findNodeByData(T)' in 'com.starosti.datastructures.linkedlist.LinkedList'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`  in the line that `findNodeByData` is defined in `SinglyLinkedList<T>`.

How do I fix this issue? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erasure of the return types is `Optional`, yet `Optional<SinglyLinkedListNode<T>>` is not a subtype of `Optional<Node<T>>`, explaining your compiler error.

By [PECS (Producer: Extends, Consumer: Super)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), your `Node` produces the value, so it's safe to use a wildcard upper bound ("extends") on the return type of the method `findNodeByData`.

```
interface LinkedList<T> {
    Optional<? extends Node<T>> findNodeByData(T data);
}
```

This allows you to override the method in the concrete subclass with a subtype, according to covariant return types.  Also, when overriding, always include the `@Override` annotation, so the compiler can check for you if you're truly overriding the method or merely overloading it accidentally.

```
class SinglyLinkedList<T> implements LinkedList<T> {
    @Override
    public Optional<SinglyLinkedListNode<T>> findNodeByData(T data){
        // ...
    }
}
```